# Get data from wifi device to windows phone app

Tags: c#, tcp, windows-phone, wifi, network-protocols

I writing a windows phone application, and i'm trying to get an image from a laptop through wifi (both mobile and pc are connected to the same wifi network).

Have an idea how can I do that? should I use wifi api or it's a regular tcp/udp connection?

Please help!
Thanks a lot!

Comment: So many options!  Bluetooth or NFC and WiFi Direct are all good options.  http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Proximity-Sample-88129731/ However NFC and WiFi direct are highly hardware dependent.

Comment: @Jeff Sanders - MSFT thank you! but what about simple tcp/udp listener? wp and pc are in the same network (wifi), but sending and receiving data is not a simple client-server arch?

Comment: Absolutely.  You could and manage the your own TCP protocol!  Again, a lot of different options are available to you.